# MS Word VBA how to tell if Range is within a Frame

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm stepping through my document paragraph by paragraph, performing certain actions depending on its contents, position, etc. I need to know whether the paragraph in question is with a frame (not a textbox, but a frame that is created using Insert Frame). So far, have come up short. Best I can cypher right now is to expand the Range by a couple lines in each direction, and then to see if the new range contains a frame using opara.Range.frames.Count.

Does anyone else have suggestions on how to tell if a range is within a frame?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard, think I answered it myself. Upon further investigation, looks like oPara.Range.Frames.Count returns "1" if range is within a frame.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/46676-how-tell-if-range-within-frame.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184